# Changing String element in an ArrayList<List<String>> is changing both Lists in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is the code I am using

```
    ArrayList<List<String>> sentanceParts = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    int i;

    sentanceParts.add(Arrays.asList(sentance.split("\\s+")));
    sentanceParts.add(sentanceParts.get(0));
    System.out.printf( "%s\n", sentanceParts.get(1).get(0));

    for( i = 0; i < sentanceParts.get(0).size(); i++ ){
        sentanceParts.get(0).set(i, 
        sentanceParts.get(0).get(i).replaceAll( "[^aeiou]+", "" ));
        System.out.printf( "%s:%d\n",
                sentanceParts.get(1).get(i),
                sentanceParts.get(0).get(i).length() );
    }
```

And it is outputting this

```
Type a sentance for analysis...
test case
e:1
ae:2
```

which should be

```
Type a sentance for analysis...
test case
test:1
case:2
```

Why is my code not doing this? I thought I was setting the sentanceParts(0) not sentanceParts(1)

Comment: The debugger is a wonderful thing. By learning how to use it you will have one more tool in your arsenal.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the debugger but it is too complicated to figure out why a reference was being made in two places as apposed to a copy of the data in memory when I have only been programming in this language for 10 something minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
sentanceParts.add(sentanceParts.get(0));
```

`sentanceParts` is referencing the same `List<String>` twice.

If you want to add a *copy* of the `List` at element `0`, then write:

```
sentanceParts.add(new ArrayList<String>(sentanceParts.get(0)));
```

Comment: You already got the answer for duplication above: The constructor "new ArrayList(otherList)" makes a copy for you.